# É possível pegar o nome de uma variável e utiliza-la como uma string?

Tags: php

É possível pegar o nome de uma variável e utiliza-la como uma string ?
Situação:
Tenho uma form cheia de inputs quando as envio as passo com seu nome e valor certo, só que preciso também atualiza-las no BD usando sua id correta para inserir, na input o value é utilizado para passar urls. dai eu estava pensando em dar a id no nome recebendo então `Array( "id_1"=>"http://exemplo.com")`. Mas preciso da ID para inserir na linha correta do BD.

```
          <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nomeDasTabelas['value']; $i ++) {
            $aux = $i + 1;
            echo '<div class="object">
                <form method="GET" action="index.php">
                <div class="grade">
                    <input type="hidden" name="serie" value="'.$aboutSerie[0].'">';

            for ($is = 0; $is < $valorDeLinks[$i]; $is ++) {
                $auxs = $is + 1;
                $tabelaDeIds = $idDosLinks[$i];
                $idDoLink = $tabelaDeIds[$is];
                $btndel = '&btn=btndel&tab=' . $nomeDasTabelas[$i] . '&id=' . $idDoLink;

                echo ($is % 4 == 0) ? '<br>' : "";
                echo '<label for="txtboxtp' . $aux . 'ep' . $auxs . '">Ep' . $auxs . '|</label>
                    <input id="txtboxtp' . $aux . 'ep' . $auxs . '" type="text" class="textbox" name="' . $is . '" value="http://">
                    <a href="index.php?serie=' . $aboutSerie[0] . $btndel . '"><button class="btndel" type="button" name="btndel" title="Excluir"><img src="../imgsys/icon_del.png" alt="Del" title="Excluir"></button></a>
                    <input type="hidden" name="ep'.$is.'" value="'.$idDoLink.'">';    
            }
```

Comment: Explique melhor seu problema, mostre um código do que está fazendo isto. Se eu entendi, praticamente não precisaria fazer nada, a não ser pela segurança.

Comment: Bom pensando aqui e resolvi criar inputs do tipo hidden e passar em seus valores a id da input que contem a URL.

Comment: Isto não mostra o que você quer fazer no banco de dados, mas cada vez mais acho que está querendo fazer algo inseguro.

Comment: Postei o código.
Então eu carreguei as URLs do BD para input para que possam ser editadas. Bom lá no BD elas tem cada uma uma id. Dai quero dar um UPDATE atualizando os valores em suas id correspondentes.

Comment: Você tem uma quantidade exata de registros retornados do BD ou pega todos que tiverem e cria quantos inputs forem necessários? Uma solução utilizando jQuery (também) serviria?

Comment: crio a quantidade necessária de inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, então vou pelo título:

**É possível pegar o nome de uma variável e utiliza-la como uma string?**

Sim, é possível, o método mais fácil de de fazer isso é explorando a sintaxe do `PHP`, onde quando se usa uma `string` com uma aspa ela não reconhece a variável como variável e sim como uma `string` normal, então uso meio que uma 'gambiarra'. Um exemplo:

```
<?php
    $minhaVariavel = "Stack Overflow";
    $nomeVariavel = '$minhaVariavel';
    $nomeVariavel = mb_substr($nomeVariavel, 1); // tira o $ do nome da variavel

    echo "Nome: ".$nomeVariavel."<br/>";
    echo "Valor: ".$minhaVariavel;
```

A saída será:

```
Nome: minhaVariavel
Valor: Stack Overflow
```

Repito novamente que não entendi muito bem a pergunta, votei para fechar por não está clara, logo fui somente pelo título. Se não for esse o objetivo da pergunta então retiro minha resposta e peço que edite a pergunta para entendermos qual a dúvida.

Comment: Ou ele pode acessar o valor assim: `echo "Valor: ${minhaVariavel}";`

Comment: Sim sim, quando se usa duas aspas (") o reconhecimento da variável é automático, as chaves {} são mais usadas para variáveis que são arrays, no caso preferi usar a concatenação. Pode ser assim `echo "Valor: ${minhaVariavel}";`, assim `echo "Valor: {$minhaVariavel}";`, ou assim `echo "Valor: $minhaVariavel";` (esse último quando a variável não é um array)